# Does HydroFill support material work with ABS?

Tags: filament, abs, dual-nozzle

I just heard about this support material that claims to be both water soluble and compatible with ABS. Is this claim true?

From what I have heard it definitely dissolves, but I am skeptical of its compatibility with the Hydrophillic ABS.

I would be particularly interested in experiences with it on a *Raise N2 plus dual*